# HTACCESS language routing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, routes

I have domain **example.com** and domain **example.fr**.

i redirect **example.fr** to **example.com** via:

```
<?php

header('location: www.example.com');
```

Here's a pseudocode of what i want to do:

*in htaccess of **example.com***

```
if HTTP_REFERER equals 'example.fr'
    redirect to example.com/fr
```

The reason i want to do this in the htaccess of **.com** (and not just in the header location of **.fr**) is that i have a lot of domains, and i want to keep it simple by editing the routing in the root domain, and not on every single domain.

i've tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example\.fr [NC]
RewriteRule /fr [R,L]
```

But no luck so far...

Any idea on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example\.fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/fr%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=302,L]
```